# Replace first instance of a string after a variable or other unique string

Tags: powershell

I have a text document broken up into sections that identify a branch location, and a placeholder that needs to be replaced only under that branch.

For example I need to replace the *'xxxxx'* with a variable only under *'### Site 3 ###'* in a new or the same text file:

```
#### Site 1 ###
jlkfd, fdjks, fdsfdsa
jlk3d, jllww, fjcnncc
xxxxx, jflkd, jfkdlww
hbubd, q0q0i, jodsssj

### Site 2 ###
jlkfd, fdjks, fdsfdsa
jlk3d, jllww, fjcnncc
xxxxx, jflkd, jfkdlww
hbubd, q0q0i, jodsssj

### Site 3 ###
jlkfd, fdjks, fdsfdsa
jlk3d, jllww, fjcnncc
xxxxx, jflkd, jfkdlww
hbubd, q0q0i, jodsssj

### Site 4 ###
jlkfd, fdjks, fdsfdsa
jlk3d, jllww, fjcnncc
xxxxx, jflkd, jfkdlww
hbubd, q0q0i, jodsssj
```

I'm thinking of something along the lines of identifying the line number I want to start at using `IndexOf()`.  I can identify the line we can start of and replace the first instance found after that line, but having a hard time finding out how to do it best.  A loop, a string method, or something else?

To actually do the replace I'm using `Replace()` for now:

```
Write-Host "new is:" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
$re = [regex]'xxxxx'
$output = $re.Replace([string]::Join("`n", ($t)), $Replace, 1)
$output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the file at 2 consecutive line breaks, then replace the string only in those chunks that match your criteria:

```
$file = 'C:\path\to\your.txt'

(Get-Content $file -Raw) -split '(?<=\r?\n)\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -like '*### Site 3 ###*') {
        $_ -replace 'xxxxx', $replace
    } else {
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $file
```

Because of the positive lookbehind assertion (`(?<=\r?\n)`) splitting the string removes only the second of the two consecutive line breaks, so that the file doesn't get mangled when `Set-Content` writes it back.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you!